# Where am I missing a comma?

Tags: database, oracle11g

```
SQL>
SQL> insert into employees values('&id','&fname','&lname','&numbermo','&yyy','&jobid','&MonthlyS','&managerID','&Did');
Enter value for id: 10
Enter value for fname: ewssfws
Enter value for lname: weffs
Enter value for numbermo: 987654321
Enter value for yyy: To_Date('2020/10/10')
Enter value for jobid: J1
Enter value for monthlys: 25000
Enter value for managerid: 20
Enter value for did: A2
old   1: insert into employees values('&id','&fname','&lname','&numbermo','&yyy','&jobid','&MonthlyS','&managerID','&Did')
new   1: insert into employees values('10','ewssfws','weffs','987654321','To_Date('2020/10/10')','J1','25000','20','A2')
insert into employees values('10','ewssfws','weffs','987654321','To_Date('2020/10/10')','J1','25000','20','A2')
                                                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

Comment: To_Date is a function - so do not add single quote before and after it.

Comment: Since the value is given as 'To_Date('2020/10/10')' without escape sequence for single quote after ( it is considering 'To_Date(' as one value and expecting comma after the value.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `y` contains single quotes, which breaks the string. You need to escape them by doubling them:

```
To_Date(''2020/10/10'')
```

Note that these are two consecutive single quotes characters (`'`), not the double quotes character (`"`).

Answer (score 0):

As Oracle tells you, error comes for the `YYY` parameter. You have to use double single quotes.

Though, applying `TO_DATE` to a string without format mask is bad practice. If I were you, I'd insert a date literal instead, which is always `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`. So:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, yyy date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, yyy) values (&id, &yyy);
Enter value for id: 1
Enter value for yyy: date '2020-08-28'
old   1: insert into test (id, yyy) values (&id, &yyy)
new   1: insert into test (id, yyy) values (1, date '2020-08-28')

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID YYY
---------- ----------------
         1 28.08.2020 00:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what issue you might have with your particular Oracle tool, but I wanted to also point out that your current call to `TO_DATE` won't work, and will generate this error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Consider this version:

```
INSERT INTO employees 
VALUES
('10', 'ewssfws', 'weffs', '987654321', date '2020-10-10', 'J1', '25000', '20', 'A2');
```

Comment: Well, it *might* work if format matches current NLS settings, but yes - I agree - that was a poor choice.